# call javascript function from jquery ui

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I have a really simple question. How do I call or execute a standard js function from within Jquery. What do I need to type into the JQuery code below to make this happen. I want the dropdown box I am creating to execute a standard js function based on item selection. Many thanks.

```
returnData = "";

(function () {

    $("#combobox").selectmenu({
        change: function (event, ui)

        {
            // console.log(ui);
            selected_value = ui.item.value;
            // alert("You selected : "+selected_value);             
            returnData = selected_value;




        }
    });
});

function update() {
    alert(returnData);
}
```

Comment: `update()` (maybe passing in `returnData`)

Comment: Won't cause problems... You can call it... afterall jQuery is javascript...

Comment: just call it as `update();` where you need to in jQuery.

Comment: A typo maybe? `$(function () {`.

Comment: keep in mind that jQuery is javascript

Comment: `jQuery` is just a `Javascript` library, so you won't find any problems mixing up things here. You can call your `update() function` anywhere in the `callback` block. Just a tip: your code doesn't show anything from the `jQuery UI` library, so please re-tag your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can directly call the Javascript from jQuery. After all Jquery is Javascript library.  You call it in the below way. Even you can pass arguments if you want.

```
returnData = "";

$(function () {

$("#combobox").selectmenu({
    change: function (event, ui)

    {
        // console.log(ui);

        selected_value = ui.item.value;
        // alert("You selected : "+selected_value);             
        returnData = selected_value;

       //you can call as below
       update();


    }
});
});

 function update() {
alert(returnData);
 }
```